# sql statement to nhibernate criteria

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

What would be the syntax in an nhibernate (version 3.3) query (criteria?) for the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT usr.* FROM User usr, User_SecurityGroup grp, SecurityGroup_Permission prm, Permission org 
WHERE usr.Id = grp.User_id AND grp.SecurityGroup_id = prm.SecurityGroup_id AND org.Id = prm.Permission_id 
AND org.Site_id IN (1,2,3) AND org.PermRead = 1 AND usr.Active = 1 AND org.Active = 1;
```

**I am unsure how the joins would be done between the tables and the criteria syntax to complete such a task.**

For this particular query, the list of Site ids will be passed in

Also the condition "org.PermRead = 1", the property name will be dynamic. so it could be "PermWrite".

Edit:
Ok so this is what I have so far

```
        ICriteria criteria = this.Session.CreateCriteria<User>();

        criteria.Add(Restrictions.In("User.Site", siteList.ToArray()));
        criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("User.Active", true));
        criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Site.Active", true));
        criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq(Enum.GetName(typeof(Perm.Types), access), true));

        criteria.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity);
        return criteria.List<User>();
```

I think a join would be in a format like this:

```
        criteria.CreateAlias("Sites", "Sites", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
```

Comment: There are several ways to join in all the NHibernate query methods. Have you tried something?

Comment: Updated the original question.

Comment: Yes, CreateAlias() (and CreateCriteria() on ICriteria will create joins along mapped associations. But the naming in the criteria code you show doesn't quite match the SQL so it's a bit hard to judge if anything is wrong. Note that if you are trying to join between entities with no mapped association, it will be much easier in HQL or LINQ.

Comment: I am pretty sure the naming is incorrect, hence my need for guidance. How would the many to many mapping be done with createalias? Are the field names on the models used for the first parameter in the createalias? NOt sure what you mean by mapped association, but there are fluent maps for all the models which specify the references/hasmany relationships.

Comment: Have you read section 15.4 (http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-associations) of the NHibernate reference? It has some simple examples. Yes, the first argument to CreateAlias() is the name of a mapped property or field on the entity where the criteria is rooted (or use "alias.proeperty"). An association is that which is mapped using e.g. References() and HasMany() in FluentNH syntax. I meant that the strings doesn't all seem equivalent to the SQL - eg. there is no apparent "Site" concept in the SQL so I don't know what it corresponds to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this:

```
       ICriteria criteria = Session.CreateCriteria<User>()
            .CreateAlias("SecurityGroups", "SecurityGroups")
            .CreateAlias("SecurityGroups.Permissions", "Permissions")
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Permissions.Active", true))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Active", true))
            .Add(Restrictions.In("Permissions.Site", ids.ToArray()))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Permissions.Perm" + Enum.GetName(typeof(Perm.Types), accessRight), Perm.Level.Allow));
        return criteria.List<User>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ICriteria criteria = Session.CreateCriteria<User>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Active", true))
    .CreateCriteria("Sites", "Site"); 
        .Add(Restrictions.In("Id", siteList.ToArray()))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Active", true))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq(access.ToString(), true))

return criteria.List<User>();
```